# r10k puppetfile install ERROR -> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, puppet

I am trying to use my local Katello mirrored Puppet Forge, but when trying to run r10k puppetfile install I get error:

ERROR    -> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

My r10k.yaml file content:

```
:cachedir: /var/cache/r10k
:sources:
  puppet:
    basedir: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments
    prefix: false
    remote: https://git.XXX.com/it/puppet.git
:forge:
  baseurl: https://kate.XXX.com
```

Maybe someone had similar problem and know how to solve it?

r10k version is 2.1.1

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I'm having the same issue.